# Screen flickering when full screen with Intel 4000 HD on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-12.04, intel-graphics, compiz

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04 - 64 bit
- Intel 4000 HD
- 8GB RAM

I've installed the latest Intel drivers from ppa packages: `ubuntu-x-swat`

The problem is that when I play a game in full screen mode, the screen flickers (the flickering isn't with a white and black background, but rather a previous image). Also when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it still opens dash. Even worse, when I close the game, my entire GUI is ruined. It overlaps the old images from the image with the current GUI and it flickers between these two and I have to reboot.

My `xorg.conf.d` has no errors in the log. I think the problem has something to do with the Intel OpenGL support or the Compiz that is installed with Ubuntu.